# Image Classification Cnn Model always give same result

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import tensorflow.keras
import tensorflow.core
import tensorflow.python
from os import listdir
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

EPOCHS = 25
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
default_image_size = tuple((256, 256))
image_size = 0
directory_root = 'C:/Users/Btl/Desktop/PlantVillage'
width=256
height=256
depth=3

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None :
            image = cv2.resize(image, default_image_size)
            return img_to_array(image)
        else :
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None


image_list, label_list = [], []
try:
        print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
        root_dir = listdir(directory_root)
        for directory in root_dir:
                # remove .DS_Store from list
                if directory == ".DS_Store":
                        root_dir.remove(directory)

        for plant_folder in root_dir:
                plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}")

                for disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
                        # remove .DS_Store from list
                        if disease_folder == ".DS_Store":
                                plant_disease_folder_list.remove(disease_folder)

                for plant_disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list:
                        print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_disease_folder} ...")
                        plant_disease_image_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/")

                        for single_plant_disease_image in plant_disease_image_list:
                                if single_plant_disease_image == ".DS_Store":
                                        plant_disease_image_list.remove(single_plant_disease_image)

                        for image in plant_disease_image_list[:200]:
                                image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{plant_disease_folder}/{image}"
                                if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".JPG") == True:
                                        image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
                                        label_list.append(plant_disease_folder)
        print("[INFO] Image loading completed")
except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")

image_size = len(image_list)

label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
image_labels = label_binarizer.fit_transform(label_list)
pickle.dump(label_binarizer,open('label_transform.pkl', 'wb'))
n_classes = len(label_binarizer.classes_)

print(label_binarizer.classes_)

np_image_list = np.array(image_list, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0

print("[INFO] Spliting data to train, test")
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np_image_list, image_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state = 42)

aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=25, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

model = Sequential()
inputShape = (height, width, depth)
chanDim = -1
if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    inputShape = (depth, height, width)
    chanDim = 1
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.summary()

opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
# distribution
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,metrics=["accuracy"])
# train the network
print("[INFO] training network...")

history = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BS),
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1
    )

acc = history.history['acc']
val_acc = history.history['val_acc']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']
epochs = range(1, len(acc) + 1)
#Train and validation accuracy
plt.plot(epochs, acc, 'b', label='Training accurarcy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'r', label='Validation accurarcy')
plt.title('Training and Validation accurarcy')
plt.legend()

plt.figure()
#Train and validation loss
plt.plot(epochs, loss, 'b', label='Training loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'r', label='Validation loss')
plt.title('Training and Validation loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print("[INFO] Calculating model accuracy")
scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {scores[1]*100}")

filename = 'label_transform.pkl'
image_labels = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

def predict_disease(image_path):
    image_array = convert_image_to_array(image_path)
    np_image = np.array(image_array, dtype=np.float16) / 225.0
    np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image,0)
    plt.imshow(plt.imread(image_path))
    result = np.argmax(model.predict_classes(np_image))
    print((image_labels.classes_[result][0]))

predict_disease('C:/Users/Betul/Desktop/PlantVillage/Pepper__bell___/Pepper__bell___healthy/0a3f2927-4410-46a3-bfda-5f4769a5aaf8___JR_HL 8275.JPG')
```

Problem is whatever i do,output result is same value,same class. im a beginner so i dont know whats wrong with this model. Please help me.

i tried changing last layer, loss func (binary,categorical,sparse), epoch count but no.

it gives same classification for 1 epoch or 50 epoch. same output.

i use this dataset and i changed them like in the image.

[Dataset directories sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLiJ8.png)

[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/emmarex/plantdisease)

Answer (score 0):

I it is due to the fact the your model is a biased model i.e. it is biased towards predicting a class i.e. it predicts the same class most of the time or all the time.This happens as a result of data imbalance. For ex say you are building a model which classifies whether a image is of dog or cat and say 80% of the dataset contains image of dog then after you train your model your model will always predict the image to be of dog.

Hence you could check if your dataset is balanced or you can use cost sensitive learning in case if you can't balance your dataset. Although balancing will definitely better.

Comment: thanks for your comment but nope. Dataset is pretty balanced. i tried this too. nothing changed. :(